# How to create table in oracle for project resource shift schedule in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

My team works in shift basis in office and I was asked to create table as show below format in Oracle apex.
The below table is for the Month of May, it changes for every month

[image]

I am just confusing, how to create a such table in Oracle as If I want to create what are the columns I should consider and how would be the structure.

I am new to Oracle apex and SQL, I am confusing like where to start and how to display?

Comment: In addition to Hari_639's suggestions below, you could also just use a classic report. Combine the day of the month with the day of the week abbreviation as the column header. Then use break formatting on the shift column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842500/oracle-sql-data-fetch-order

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gantt charts for this purpose. Oracle APEX Gantt charts are based on [Oracle JET Gantt Charts.](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=gantt&demo=basic) However, in APEX, you can just write a SQL query and APEX will generate such a chart for you.

If you are not familiar with gantt charts in APEX, you can check this [blog post](https://srihariravva.blogspot.com/2019/12/few-tips-on-gantt-charts.html).

For grouping employees based on their shift, either you can have filter on top of the region as "Select Shift" and you can display data for selected shift. This way, users can see data only for 1 shift at a time. Other option is, you can create 3 different gantt charts, one for each shift (assuming you have 3 different shifts). Or You can create only one gantt chart for all shifts and prepend shift name to employee name e.g. Morning-Rahul, Morning-Srinivas and order data by employee name.